# Non thread safe behaviour - Race condition never happens

Tags: java, multithreading

Trying this piece of code, I found out that no matter how many times I run the program or iterations are done, race conditions never occur. I know this is not thread safe and I can't understand the reason why this behavior is happening. Any documentation/ideas are welcomed.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    static final int N = 1000;
    static int ITERATIONS = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[10];
        boolean found = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < ITERATIONS; j++) {
            MyThread.val = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                threads[i].run();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    threads[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (MyThread.val != N * 10) {
                System.out.println("different !");
                found = false;
            }
        }
        if (found)
            System.out.println("The value is always correct.");
    }
}
```

MyThread

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    static int val = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.N; i++)
            val = val + 1;
    }
}
```

I tried to run the program for dozens of time, but it always prints 
"The value is always correct".

(This is not homework or whatever)

Comment: Try `threads[i].start();` instead of `threads[i].run();`

Comment: Looks to me like everything *is* thread safe because you're calling `join` on all the threads, which means that they will all complete execution before you test the value of `N`.

Comment: @Gabriel This is not the case, per the Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()

Comment: His threads ARE constructed from a separate runnable

Comment: You don't want to just call the runnable's run method though, you want to start the thread so it's multithreaded.

Comment: @Dan Bod you aren't using a multithreading in Java when using `threads[i].run()` in this case you using a single thread application. This sample is a not parallel program to simulate a race condition problem - see answer from @Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually starting any threads.  Calling `Thread.run()` simply runs the activity of the thread in the current thread.  If you were to print start and end timestamps in your method, you might observe this.

Call `Thread.start()` instead of `Thread.run()` to observe what you're looking for.

Comment: run simply calls the run method from the thread function (iterative), while start actually makes the whole process parallel, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no racing conditions because it runs in a single thread.

The method `run` simply calls the `run` method of its Runnable object without creating a new thread. (or does nothing if there is no Runnable object)

The method `start` actually starts a new thread that runs concurrently.

Docs:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--

Comment: You need to call thread.start() to start a new thread. You also have to call thread.join() to wait until it finished. Your code do not block on calling start() so maybe no thread started to run or maybe they are still running.

Comment: @thomas OP's code already calls `join`, the only mistake is calling `run` instead of `start`.

Comment: Yes, that is my fault. Just ignore the comment.

Answer (score -1):

The race condition will show in the intermediate values, but should not affect the final value. `val` will always be incremented the same number of times, it will just bounce back-and-forth between threads in incrementing it. If you stored a local `val` in each thread (with a new class) and incremented it also, you would notice that the local value was updated at a different rate than the global value, and also that this rate could vary substantially as the program ran.